# el operador '+' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo button y double

Tags: c#

trato de crear una calculadora en windows form, solo me falta programar el boton de "=", mi problema con el programa es cuando  estoy programando el boton de igual para que me muestre el resultado (de una suma, resta, multiplicacion, o division)  en un textbox me sale el siguiente error : "el operador '+'(o cualquier otro operador) no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo button y double". ¿como podria solucionarlo?

```
    private bool sumap = false ;
    private bool restp = false ;
    private bool multp = false ;
    private bool divip = false;

     private void Suma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double n1 = 0;
         sumap = true;
         restp = false;
         multp = false;
         divip = false;



    n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.ResetText();
    }

    private void Resta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double n1 = 0;
        sumap = false;
        restp = true;
        multp = false;
        divip = false;

        n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.ResetText();
    }

    private void Multiplicacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double n1 = 0;
        sumap = false;
        restp = false;
        multp = true;
        divip = false;
        n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.ResetText();
    }

    private void Division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double n1 = 0;
        sumap = false;
        restp = false;
        multp = false;
        divip = true;

        n1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.ResetText();
    }

    private void igual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        double n2 = 0;

        double r;
        n2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);


        if (sumap)
        {
            r = n1 + n2;

            textBox1.Text = r.ToString();
        }

        else if (restp)
        {
            r = n1 - n2;

            textBox1.Text = r.ToString();
        }

        else if (multp)
        {
            r = n1 * n2;
            textBox1.Text = r.ToString();
        }

        else if (divip)
        {
            r = n1 / n2;
            textBox1.Text = r.ToString();
        }
    }
```

no puse la parte de los botones de numeros que el post no sea muy largo.

los errores ocurren donde esta "r = n1(+ ,- , * , /)n2;

---

@Miguel Marroquin. ya declare n1 como global pero ahora tengo estos nuevos errores:

donde declaro la variable como global me dice: "el tipo Form1 ya contiene una definicion para n1.

en el boton de igual: "ambiguedad entre Form1.n1 y Form1.n1.

```
private bool sumap = false ;
    private bool restp = false ;
    private bool multp = false ;
    private bool divip = false;
    public double n1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable n1 no está definida en button1_click. Debes definir n1 de forma global, para poder acceder a ella desde cualquier lugar. Al parecer si está definida en algún lugar pero no de tipo double.

Si te marca un error de ambigüedad, quiere decir que uno de los botones en el formulario se llama n1. Entonces debes renombrar tu botón, o usar otro nombre para tu variable que no sea n1.

Comment: Ok parecia que n1 tambien era el nombre de uno de mis botones, ya lo solucione y funciona correctamente. gracias Miguel.

Comment: Favor de marcar esta respuesta como correcta.

Comment: @alansmith si esta respuesta te sirvió para solucionar el problema, por favor, márcala como aceptada.